# Function test fails

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit, functional-testing

I'm trying to do functional test for the routes that are behind the firewall. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong but the test for the route `admin/dashboard` fails. Any ideas?

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Tests;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;
use Symfony\Component\BrowserKit\Cookie;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken;

class ApplicationAvailabilityFunctionalTest extends WebTestCase
{

    private $client;

    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->client = self::createClient();
    }

    /**
     * @dataProvider urlProvider
     */
    public function testPageIsSuccessful($url)
    {

        $this->client->request('GET', $url);

        $this->assertTrue($this->client->getResponse()->isSuccessful());
    }

    public function urlProvider()
    {
        $this->logIn();

        return array(
            array('/'),
            array('/admin/login'),
            array('/admin/dashboard'),
        );
    }

    public function logIn()
    {

        $this->client = self::createClient();
        $session = $this->client->getContainer()->get('session');

        $firewall = 'our_db_provider';
        $token = new UsernamePasswordToken('admin', 'admin', $firewall, array('ROLE_ADMIN'));
        $session->set('_security_'.$firewall, serialize($token));
        $session->save();

        $cookie = new Cookie($session->getName(), $session->getId());
        $this->client->getCookieJar()->set($cookie);
    }
}
```

//UPDATE

Here's the error I get

```
1) AppBundle\Tests\ApplicationAvailabilityFunctionalTest::testPageIsSuccessful with data set #2 ('/admin/dashboard')
Failed asserting that false is true.

/Users/me/Projects/cms/src/AppBundle/Tests/ApplicationAvailabilityFunctionalTest.php:27
```

//UPDATE 2

Here's the dump of $token variable

`Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken {#488
  -credentials: null
  -providerKey: "security"
  -user: "admin"
  -roles: array:1 [
    0 => Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Role\Role {#487
      -role: "ROLE_ADMIN"
    }
  ]
  -authenticated: true
  -attributes: []
}`

//UPDATE 3

```
`security:
    encoders:
        AppBundle\Entity\Admin\User:
            algorithm: bcrypt
    providers:
        our_db_provider:
            entity:
               class: AppBundle\Entity\Admin\User
               property: username
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/admin/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
    firewalls:
        default:
            anonymous: ~
            http_basic: ~
            form_login:
               login_path: /admin/login
               check_path: /admin/login_check
               csrf_provider: security.csrf.token_manager
            logout:
               path:   /admin/logout
               target: /admin/login
            provider: our_db_provider
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        main:
            anonymous: ~`
```

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: Apparently there is no such route. Does `app/console debug:router ` show anything related to `/admin/dashboard`?

Comment: The route exists. It loads fine in browser. Here's the output of debug:router
`app_admin_dashboard            ANY    ANY    ANY  /admin/dashboard`

Comment: Where is `$url` declared?

Answer (score 0):

The route is not public

The failing test is on the `/admin/dashboard` route that probably is protected by authentication so the server response is not successfully (200 OK) but (403 access denied or 302 redirect)

So  you must test your route differently: the route is protected so check for 403 or that redirect to login page

Check the doc about [How to Simulate Authentication with a Token in a Functional Test](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/testing/simulating_authentication.html)

And test that an authenticated user see correctly the page

Comment: Yes, the route is protected by the firewall. That's why I'm using method logIn(). Probably I'm missing something there...

Comment: Hi @Vodokan you need to do the login, check the [doc here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/testing/simulating_authentication.html) for further detail on how implement the authentication in a functional test

Comment: Please, see again the code I posted. I did everything described from the page you referrer to.

Comment: Hi @Vodokan very strange, check the `app/log/test.log` for investigate about the problem

Comment: I didn't know about existing of the test.log file. Anyway I found this line ` security.DEBUG: Access denied, the user is not fully authenticated; redirecting to authentication entry point`

Comment: @Vodokan, ok, check that the firewall name is correct (not the provider) as example, referring to an example complete reference described [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html#full-default-configuration) the variable `$firewall`must be set to `somename`. Hope this help

Comment: Hi @Vodokan same issue? Can you post the relevant part of your security.yml?

Comment: Already tried to set the firewall to default but got the same error